# Symofony 3.3 How to force user log out?

Tags: php, session-cookies, symfony-3.3

I have given the users the option to delete themselves from a company and after that I have to deactivate their account and force them logout. But if the rememerme cookie is set, the user it not logged out, no matter what. 
This is the code I am using to force logout the user.

```
        $this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken(null);
        $this->get("session")->invalidate(true);

        $targetUrl = $this->generateUrl("logout");
```

and then I send a response with that logout url. How can I unset the rememberme cookie, note: I have multiple rememberme cookies for different systems inside the main system.

Thanks.

Comment: What keeps you from invalidating that rememberme cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try removing the cookie.

Something like this:

```
unset($_COOKIE['remember_user']);
setcookie('remember_user', null, -1, '/');
```

Comment: Thank you, the cookie name was "REMEMBERME" and some other cookies which I was using. I had to unset them.